# Django rest framework: use sqlalchemy models instead of django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlalchemy

I have an application with 500+ tables and their models are written in sqlalchemy.
I want to use these models in django application instead of writing all models again in django. I have tried [django-rest-witchcraft](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-witchcraft/) but it does not work. Please suggest me more reliable solution

Comment: try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried inspectdb but the problem with that is I have to change models in both sqlalchemy and django if I do some changes with db tables or create new tables.
I just want to use sqlalchemy models not django models.

Comment: what specifically has not worked for you in witchcraft? did you get any errors? (disclosure Im one of contributors). if there are issues feel free to file issues

Comment: In witchcraft's documentation it is not specified that ModelSerializer should be imported from rest_witchcraft.serializers, 

this viewset worked for me


`class CommunityViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Community.query
    model = Community
    serializer_class = CommunitySerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    permission_classes = (MyPermissionClass,)
`

Comment: @miki725 also witchcraft has limitations, like you can not get data by id like we normaly do with rest framework views.

Comment: @NaumanSharif do you mean something like `/resource/<id>/` ? that pattern is supported out of the box. do you mean something else?

Comment: yes exactly
also I have problem with parent child relations
like in hotel and rooms relations
I am able to get hotel in rooms API but can not get rooms in hotels API